# IE7 select option text color not displayed correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-7

I am working with IE7. I got the following CSS rule:

```
form [disabled] {
    color: #999 !important;
}
```

In a jQuery ready() event I disable every option in a SELECT:

```
$('#mySelect option').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

and then enable some of those disabled options again:

```
('#myOption').removeAttr('disabled');
```

Now all looks fine. In this case every option has a grey text except the first one.

But if I change the disabled attribute of one option after the page load, e.g. after a click on a button the color does not change anymore.

If I inspect a option with IE7 developer toolbar I can clearly see that the disabled attribute is gone and the color is set to the original color again (other then grey) but the option still hast grey text.

It's the same the other way around. If I put the disabled attribute on an option that was not disabled before, I can see the attrbibute set in developer toolbar and I can see that the color is set to the one defined in the CSS but I cannot see it in the actual browser window. Still the old color.

This is some very weird behaviour and I know that IE7 has this bug (or feature?) not dealing with disabled form elements at all.

But I want at least to have a grey color on the items a user should not select. I cannot get this to work properly.

Is there any way how I can get this to work?

Comment: Does `!important` work on IE7?

Answer (score 1):

As a simple work-around, you could set a class `disabled` on the elements, when you're disabling them.

JS:

```
$('#mySelect option').addClass('disabled').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

JS:

```
('#myOption').removeClass('disabled').removeAttr('disabled');
```

CSS:

```
form .disabled {
    color: #999 !important;
}
```

Comment: The problem does not seem the CSS. As the developer toolbar tells me, the color is actually applied correctly to the options. IE7 just does not render it accordingly.